# Excel vba: slow down after inspecting object in locals window

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to inspect an object when a new instance is created. The instance is created with a function `DaySchedule.Create()`. I can do that because I set the attribute `VB_PredeclaredId = True`. Here's the code of the function:

```
Public Function Create( _
   ByVal Name As String, _
   ByVal Cycle As Long, _
   ByVal Prio As Long, _
   ByVal startDate As Date, _
   ByVal WeekDays As String) As WeekSchedule
   Dim WeekDays_Arr() As String
   Dim Days As Variant

   me_Monday = False
   me_Tuesday = False
   me_Wednesday = False
   me_Thursday = False
   me_Friday = False
   me_Saturday = False
   me_Sunday = False

   WeekDays_Arr = Split(WeekDays, ";")
   For Each Days In WeekDays_Arr

      Select Case Days
         Case "Mo": me_Monday = True
         Case "Tu": me_Tuesday = True
         Case "We": me_Wednesday = True
         Case "Th": me_Thursday = True
         Case "Fr": me_Friday = True
         Case "Sa": me_Saturday = True
         Case "Su": me_Sunday = True
      End Select
   Next Days

   me_ScheduleType = "weekly"
   me_Name = Name
   me_Cycle = Cycle
   me_Prio = Prio
   me_StartDate = startDate

   Set Create = Me
End Function
```

The problem is whenever I open the locals window and try to expand `Me` Excel is loading infinitly. Sometimes it works after 20 seconds or so, but then every line take's 20 seconds. My CPU load is only 15% and I dont have other functions in the Excel workbook that might be calculated. Yesterday I have done exactly the same thing and it expanded instantly. Does anyone have a similar issue or the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem lied in a property named `Schedule_NextBackup`. The Get-property didn't set a property but calculated something. I changed it to a function and it doesn't lag anymore.